# Does anyone here know how to view the source code of the Action subscription method

Tags: c#

And I have a problem,I create a new Appdomain like this:

```
public class Test{

void Method{

 var testDomain=Appdomain.Create("TestDomain");

 var targetClass= (TargetClass)testDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap("SomeDll","ClassName");  //then I want to Regist a Method to the Action in targetClass,

 targetClass.changeEvent+= localMethod;//but when runing here, throw a EX about my Test class is not have Serializable Attribute ,and I hava no idea to know what happent ,so would anybody like helpe me to know why Test class need Serializable Attribute.

 }

 public void localMethod(){

 do something

}

}
public class TargetClass{

public event Action changeEvent;

}
```

I try to use DnSpy view the source code ,but I find nothing,is look like outside implementation,

Answer (score 1):

Only those classes that will be passed by value should be marked with `Seralizable` attribute.
If you want to get a reference, then you need to inherit from `MarshalByRefObject` otherwise the object instance will not be able to pass between domains because it is either copied or a transparent proxy for accessing methods in another domain is created.

Comment: so I  mark  Seralizable attribute to Test class   is wrong way，Although it s still work。Maybe I need to  figure out if I need to hold  the refences of this object.  
 and ,Thank you very much for your help.